# Create Rectangle of map extent using Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on Cordova application using Google Maps Javascript API v3, where the user should have the option to set an "area of interest".  This area of interest should be visualized by a polygon or actually by an rectangle. 
I've thought that it would be the easiest to use the ["getBounds" method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#methods), but unfortunately this give me the LatLngBounds, which is hard to use for rectangle as I have to construct the rectangle by hand.
As far as I know, a rectangle consists for this case of five points...

Is there any other smart(er) way to do so?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use a rectangle rather than a polygon?

Comment: You're absolutely right! For my understanding, a rectangle is a polygon :P... So sorry for the misunderstanding...I've edited my question to clarify my question.

Comment: They are different objects in the Google Maps Javascript API though... [google.maps.Rectangle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Rectangle) - [google.maps.Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Polygon).  A google.maps.Rectangle takes a `google.maps.LatLngBounds` object to define its size and position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
function setBounds() {
    if (rectangle && rectangle.setBounds) {
        rectangle.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    } else {
      rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        bounds: map.getBounds()
      });    
    }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/f1Lnmxc7/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var rectangle;
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {
      lat: 33.678,
      lng: -116.243
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

  rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(33.671, -116.251),
      new google.maps.LatLng(33.685, -116.234))
  });
}

function setBounds() {
  if (rectangle && rectangle.setBounds) {
    rectangle.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  } else {
    rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      bounds: map.getBounds()
    });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input type="button" value="set bounds" onclick="setBounds();" />
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Dear @geocodezip,
Thanks for your answer and your provided example. This helped me a lot :)